# Invoke ViewComponent after action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have following layout page:

```
<body>
<nav>@Component.Invoke("Navigation")</nav>
<main>@RenderBody()</main>
</body>
```

`ViewComponent` which renders two different views for authenticated and not authenticated users:

```
public class NavigationViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return View("User");
        }
        return View("Guest");
    }
}
```

I also have an action method to log out the user:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    ...
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

I want to render `ViewComponent` **after** the the `LogOut` action method is invoked, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. All I need to do, is to `RedirectToAction()`, instead of returning a View.